# Google Analytics Mobile APP logs say connected but realtimetracking says 0 users

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, google-analytics

so i'm using angular and the [cordova Google analytics plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin)

And the logs say i'm connected but the view in google analytics doesn't show any users connected to my app. does anyone see what i'm missing?

This is how i setup the connection:

```
        var auth = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['auth'])
        var userID = auth.userID;

        $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.debugMode();
        $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-55148678-1');
        $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.setUserId(userID);
        $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.trackView('We Alert Map');
```

And these are the logs:

```
09-25 14:24:18.712: W/ContextImpl(31566): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/ext_sd/Android/data/nl.studionewmedia.wealert/files
09-25 14:24:18.712: W/ContextImpl(31566): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/ext_sd/Android/data/nl.studionewmedia.wealert/files
09-25 14:24:18.712: W/ContextImpl(31566): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/ext_sd/Android/data/nl.studionewmedia.wealert/cache
09-25 14:24:23.012: W/CordovaPlugin(31566): Attempted to send a second callback for ID: UniversalAnalytics712371046
09-25 14:24:23.012: W/CordovaPlugin(31566): Result was: "Invalid action"
09-25 14:24:23.022: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[JavaBridge,5,main]: Dispatch period set with null handler. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.
09-25 14:24:23.022: W/CordovaPlugin(31566): Attempted to send a second callback for ID: UniversalAnalytics712371048
09-25 14:24:23.022: W/CordovaPlugin(31566): Result was: "Invalid action"
09-25 14:24:28.032: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
09-25 14:24:28.062: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
09-25 14:24:28.062: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@41c5e138
09-25 14:24:28.072: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
09-25 14:24:28.072: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
09-25 14:24:28.072: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
09-25 14:24:28.072: I/GAV3(31566): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
09-25 14:24:28.072: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
09-25 14:24:28.072: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: uid=2,  v=1,  ul=nl-nl,  t=appview,  ht=1411647863039,  sr=1080x1776,  an=WeAlert,  tid=UA-55148678-1,  aid=nl.studionewmedia.wealert,  cid=349fa948-5bb3-4562-824e-3001b02cf401,  av=0.0.1,  _u=.KnoKoK-AL,  cd=We Alert Map,  
09-25 14:25:01.652: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
09-25 14:25:01.652: V/GAV3(31566): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: uid=2,  v=1,  ul=nl-nl,  t=appview,  ht=1411647901665,  sr=1080x1776,  an=WeAlert,  tid=UA-55148678-1,  aid=nl.studionewmedia.wealert,  cid=349fa948-5bb3-4562-824e-3001b02cf401,  av=0.0.1,  _u=.r3oK-AL,  cd=Volgend,
```

It's also wrapped in the

[ngCordova extensions](http://ngcordova.com/docs/#GoogleAnalytics) of the plugin.

Comment: time I suppose, the connected devices are not reflected real time. There is a 3-7 mins of lag.

Comment: Um yea so it seems it was just time, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with time, it seems the analytics real time view has a 3-7 mins lag. Thanks to @Eu.Dr. For pointing this out. posting this answer for future readers.